# Cannot install wine i386 after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wine

I have tried every guide out there and cannot get wine i386 installed after upgrading my system from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.

Following the WineHQ documentation gets me into dependency hell (requiring libfaudio0:i386 among other things, which is also impossible to install), and installing wine from the official Ubuntu repos ends up with errors like as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32-development".

Is there a different way to install it if you upgraded from 18.04 as opposed to clean 20.04 install?

EDIT:
When I run any wine command I get the following:
`as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32-development"`

When I try to install an msi file with `wine msiexec /i /path/to/file` I get the following:
`003e:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\\windows\\syswow64\\msiexec.exe" not supported on this system`

EDIT 2:

```
$ apt-cache policy $(dpkg -l | grep wine | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}')
carla-bridge-wine32:
  Installed: 5:2.3.1+git20210723
  Candidate: 5:2.3.1+git20210723
  Version table:
 *** 5:2.3.1+git20210723 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
carla-bridge-wine64:
  Installed: 5:2.3.1+git20210723
  Candidate: 5:2.3.1+git20210723
  Version table:
 *** 5:2.3.1+git20210723 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
libkwineffects12:
  Installed: 4:5.18.5-0ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 4:5.18.5-0ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 4:5.18.5-0ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4:5.18.4.1-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
    

$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.1~focal-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ sudo apt install --install-recommends wine-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 6.0.1~focal-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ sudo apt install --install-recommends wine-stable-i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable-i386:i386 : Depends: libfaudio0:i386 (>= 19.06.07) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libsane1:i386
                         Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

EDIT 3:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep wine
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
```

EDIT 4:

```
$ sudo aptitude search ~o
i A aspnetcore-runtime-2.2                                                                            - Microsoft ASP.NET Core 2.2.8 Shared Framework                                                               
i   carla-bridge-wine32                                                                               - Dummy package                                                                                               
i   carla-git                                                                                         - audio plugin host                                                                                           
i   carla-git-data                                                                                    - audio plugin host (common data)                                                                             
i A containerd.io                                                                                     - An open and reliable container runtime                                                                      
i   discord                                                                                           - Chat for Communities and Friends                                                                            
i   docker-ce                                                                                         - Docker: the open-source application container engine                                                        
i A docker-ce-cli                                                                                     - Docker CLI: the open-source application container engine                                                    
i A docker-ce-rootless-extras                                                                         - Rootless support for Docker.                                                                                
i A docker-scan-plugin                                                                                - Docker scan cli plugin.                                                                                     
i A dotnet-host                                                                                       - Microsoft .NET Host - 5.0.8                                                                                 
i A dotnet-hostfxr-2.2                                                                                - Microsoft .NET Core Host FX Resolver - 2.2.8 2.2.8                                                          
i A dotnet-runtime-2.2                                                                                - Microsoft .NET Core Runtime - 2.2.8 Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.8                                             
i A dotnet-runtime-deps-2.2                                                                           - dotnet-runtime-deps-2.2 2.2.8                                                                               
i   dotnet-sdk-2.2                                                                                    - Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.2.402                                                                             
i   dropbox                                                                                           - cloud synchronization engine - CLI and Nautilus extension                                                   
i   insomnia                                                                                          - The Collaborative API Client and Design Tool                                                                
i   kxstudio-default-settings                                                                         - KXStudio default settings and config                                                                        
i A kxstudio-menu                                                                                     - KXStudio Menu                                                                                               
i   kxstudio-repos                                                                                    - KXStudio repositories                                                                                       
i A libavcodec57                                                                                      - FFmpeg library with de/encoders for audio/video codecs - runtime files                                      
i   libavresample3                                                                                    - FFmpeg compatibility library for resampling - runtime files                                                 
i   libavutil55                                                                                       - FFmpeg library with functions for simplifying programming - runtime files                                   
i   libffi6                                                                                           - Foreign Function Interface library runtime                                                                  
i   libgig8                                                                                           - library for accessing Gigasampler, DLS, SoundFont, KORG, AKAI files                                         
i   libicu60                                                                                          - International Components for Unicode                                                                        
i A libicu65                                                                                          - International Components for Unicode                                                                        
i   liblinuxsampler                                                                                   - realtime audio sampler (base library)                                                                       
i   libmysofa0                                                                                        - library to read HRTFs stored in the AES69-2015 SOFA format                                                  
i A libonig4                                                                                          - regular expressions library                                                                                 
i   libpng12-0                                                                                        - PNG library - runtime                                                                                       
i   libpostproc54                                                                                     - FFmpeg library for post processing - runtime files                                                          
i   libpython3.6                                                                                      - Shared Python runtime library (version 3.6)                                                                 
i   libpython3.6-minimal                                                                              - Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.6)                                                         
i   libpython3.6-stdlib                                                                               - Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 3.6)                             
i   libreadline7                                                                                      - GNU readline and history libraries, run-time libraries                                                      
i   libsndio6.1                                                                                       - Small audio and MIDI framework from OpenBSD, runtime libraries                                              
i   libswresample2                                                                                    - FFmpeg library for audio resampling, rematrixing etc. - runtime files                                       
i   libswscale4                                                                                       - FFmpeg library for image scaling and various conversions - runtime files                                    
i   libvpx5                                                                                           - VP8 and VP9 video codec (shared library)                                                                    
i   libx264-152                                                                                       - x264 video coding library                                                                                   
i   libx265-146                                                                                       - H.265/HEVC video stream encoder (shared library)                                                            
i   libzip4                                                                                           - library for reading, creating, and modifying zip archives (runtime)                                         
i   minecraft-launcher                                                                                - Official Minecraft Launcher                                                                                 
i A mono-llvm-support                                                                                 - Mono runtime - SGen                                                                                         
i A mono-llvm-tools                                                                                   - opt and llc for Mono llvm mode                                                                              
i A mono-roslyn                                                                                       - Microsoft C# compiler                                                                                       
i A msbuild                                                                                           - build platform for .NET and Visual Studio                                                                   
i A msbuild-libhostfxr                                                                                - Helper library for MSbuild .NET Core support                                                                
i A msbuild-sdkresolver                                                                               - build platform for .NET and Visual Studio                                                                   
i   packages-microsoft-prod                                                                           - Apt configuration for packages.microsoft.com                                                                
i A pgdg-keyring                                                                                      - keyring for apt.postgresql.org                                                                              
i A php8.0-common                                                                                     - documentation, examples and common module for PHP                                                           
i   php8.0-curl                                                                                       - CURL module for PHP                                                                                         
i   php8.0-mbstring                                                                                   - MBSTRING module for PHP                                                                                     
i   php8.0-zip                                                                                        - Zip module for PHP                                                                                          
i A postgresql-client-10                                                                              - front-end programs for PostgreSQL 10                                                                        
i A postgresql-client-11                                                                              - front-end programs for PostgreSQL 11                                                                        
i A postgresql-client-13                                                                              - front-end programs for PostgreSQL 13                                                                        
i   python-psycopg2                                                                                   - Python module for PostgreSQL                                                                                
i A referenceassemblies-pcl                                                                           - Portable Library Reference Assemblies for .NET                                                              
i   sitala                                                                                            - Drum sampler                                                                                                
i A steam-launcher                                                                                    - Launcher for the Steam software distribution service                                                        
i   systray-x                                                                                         - SysTray-X is a system tray extension for Thunderbird 68+ (KDE).                                             
i   teams                                                                                             - Microsoft Teams for Linux is your chat-centered workspace in Office 365.                                    
i   teamviewer                                                                                        - Remote control and meeting solution.                                                                        
i   yarn                                                                                              - Fast, reliable, and secure dependency management.                                                           

$ sudo apt-cache policy wine-stable-i386
wine-stable-i386:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6.0.1~focal-1
  Version table:
     6.0.1~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.0.1~bionic-1 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     6.0.0~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.0.4~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.0.3~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.0.2~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.0.1~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     4.0.4~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: Please show us actual input and output in your question. Summaries lack sufficient detail to understand your specific problem.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: Edit your question to answer: Does installing the `wine32-development` package solve the first error?

Comment: I'm unable to install wine32-development. I end up in dependency hell, with one i386 package being required after another, none of which I am able to install.

Comment: Since you have not shown us the complete dependency hell output, not much we can help with. Your summaries lack sufficient detail to understand your specific problem.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy $(dpkg -l | grep wine | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}')` to the question body by editing it.

Comment: Updated again. If I attempt to install `wine-stable` as the message suggests, I get another dependency issue, then another, and another etc etc.

Comment: What is the output of `aptitude search ~o`  and `apt-cache policy wine-stable-i386`?

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 1):

There something wrong with your repositories or local package lists. The faudio library is [available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libfaudio0) in official Ubuntu repositories since 20.04 LTS from *universe* pocket.

To install above listed packages you have to add i386 architecture to the system by

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

and add *universe* pocket by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
```

then update package lists by

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and install wine as you planned by

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends wine-stable-i386
```

If above command fails, then install Aptitude and try to install Wine with it

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install wine-stable-i386
```

Also I suppose that your versions of `carla-bridge-wine` came from some thirdparty repository, so you have to downgrade them by

```
sudo apt-get install carla-bridge-wine32=2.1-0ubuntu1 carla-bridge-wine64=2.1-0ubuntu1
```

If all above fails - then switch to Main Ubuntu software mirror and run all above commands again.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these work.  The `universe` repo was already there.  `apt` installing `wine-stable-i386` starts the dependency rabbit hole with `libfaudio0:i386`, and aptitude attempts to install things but actually just ends up removing a whole bunch of things that I do use (emacs, ag, plasma-desktop, etc etc) and doesn't actually install any of the wine i386 requirements.

`carla-bridge-wine` is from KXstudio repos.

At this point I think a re-install is the only option left.

Answer (score 0):

In my case: docker witch node and java and electron this works - I left full dockerfile

```docker
FROM node:16.15.0

WORKDIR /work
COPY package.json .

RUN apt update
RUN apt-get -y install zip unzip

# node_modules witch angular and electron
RUN npm install -g n @angular/cli electron electron-builder

# JAVA
RUN apt-get -y install default-jre
RUN apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless 

# Wine (Wine32)
RUN apt install -y software-properties-common
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
RUN apt-key add winehq.key
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ buster main'
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install --install-recommends winehq-stable

EXPOSE 3002
```